# What Google Cloud API permissions do I have to grant to an API key used by Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I found out today that API Key created for Firebase in Google Cloud Console has unrestricted API access by default.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

I was able to restrict its usage to my app by setting iOS bundle id. However, I want to go further and limit its access to certain APIs that Firebase actually uses, instead of leaving it to `Unrestricted`, 
*(e.g. I don't want to give my iOS app API key unrestricted access to call `Kubernetes API` or `BigQuery API` which it doesn't use)*

The API credential detail page contains a select box with list of checkboxes that I can check to restrict the access.

Some of the API names are explicit, but some are just confusing, and I cannot seem to figure out restricted set of APIs that I need to check to use each Firebase feature.

- For instance, there is `Firebase Remote Config API` which I need to check to make Firebase Remote Config to work in my app, and `Firebase Dynamic Link API` which I need to check to make Firebase Dynamic Link to work.
- However, I don't necessarily have to check `Cloud Firestore API` to make Firebase Firestore to work? Firebase Firestore just seems to work without I granting any permission for it in API credentials page.
- In another case, there is no explicit API checkbox for `Firebase Authentication`, but I will need to check `Identity Toolkit API` and `Token Service API` to make Firebase auth to work correctly, and none of the Firebase doc seems to talk about these. (I tried with a lot of manual trial and errors to figure this out, as there were other APIs with similar names `Identity and Access Management (IAM) API`, and `IAM Service Account Credentials API`.)
- For FCM, I see two, `FCM Registration API` and `Firebase Cloud Messaging API` checkboxes, and I am unsure of differences between these two.
- I don't see checkbox row for `Firebase Crashlytics`. Does it mean it is going to work without any permission whitelisting?

I want to know if Firebase team provides a doc that goes over these Firebase <-> Google Cloud API mappings so that users can properly restrict their API key for security reasons.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the right place to ask for references to documentation.  I suggest contacting Firebase support directly with your concerns (and you seem to have many).  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: This is a valid question that many developers can benefit from. If you or someone else finds good cohesive answer, please do share!